# A pretty GUI for autotest

Tags: ruby, autotest, zentest

I was wondering if anyone knows of any nice GUIs for autotest?

I already know about all the plugins distributed with autotest (growl, knotify etc.), what I want is a little more.

I would like a GUI that displays the total count of failed tests at all times. 
I would like the GUI to allow me to click through to the failing test (have them open them in vim) 
I would like to see the stack trace next to each failing test. But I don't want the view too cluttered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW I started a [new project](http://github.com/SamSaffron/autotest-shoes-gui/tree/master) on github which aims to solve this problem. It's really basic at the moment, but it works for me.

Here is a pic

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance it's not what you're looking for since it's an entire IDE, but Netbeans has some really neat Ruby testing support:
http://www.netbeans.org/features/ruby/index.html

> The built-in testing framework in
>   Ruby, Test::Unit, is supported
>   directly. You can create new unit
>   tests from the New menu. You run your
>   unit tests by just invoking Run File
>   (Shift-F6) on files. This opens a test
>   results window with the output from
>   executing the unit tests and test
>   result statistics. Double-clicking the
>   nodes in the statistics panel takes
>   you to the corresponding declaration
>   location in the editor, and you can
>   navigate to the next/previous failure
>   using the arrow buttons.

[alt text http://wiki.netbeans.org/attach/RubyTesting/testrunner-1%20.png](http://wiki.netbeans.org/attach/RubyTesting/testrunner-1%20.png)

You also get test coverage (it will color code your files as well so you can immediately see what what lines are tested and what aren't):

[alt text http://blogs.sun.com/tor/resource/ruby-coveragereport.png](http://blogs.sun.com/tor/resource/ruby-coveragereport.png)

Comment: That's neat ... but Im very much a Vim guy

Comment: And now RoR support is being dropped from NetBeans: http://jaxenter.com/oracle-drop-ruby-on-rails-from-netbeans-and-jboss-tools-3-2-rc1-released-34645.html